Copying dependencies from one project to another gives Unresolved reference error
I cloned a repository of an Android app (https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack) and ran it in Android Studio, it worked fine.
Then I created a new project, tried copying plugins in build.gradle.kts(Module:app) and sync the project, I get this error:

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:public val  Class<TypeVariable(T)>.kotlin: KClass<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.jvm

When I tried copying dependencies in build.gradle.kts(Project), I get this error:

Unresolved reference: iconsExtended, for implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material.iconsExtended)

(It worked fine in the cloned app)
Why do I get an error for the dependencies?
Also if I try adding material dependency
libs.androidx.compose.material

when the default was material3
libs.androidx.material3

Android Studio can not load the material package even after removing material3.

Plugins usually need to be defined both in the app level gradle file and then applied in each module where you actually want to use them.
All dependencies and plugins that start with lib and are not a string literal (i.e. enclosed in double quotes "") are defined in your version catalog. That is a file called libs.versions.toml usually located in your project's gradle directory. This file is only a static configuration file that cannot be executed like your other gradle files, it only contains the definition of the gradle artifacts with their version numbers. Hence, you need to also copy over the content of this file.
You can read more on how to migrate to version catalogs here: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs
